# Php Script not working on Wamp Localhost but working fine on remote server

Tags: php, session, localhost, wamp

When I open `index.php` on **localhost** - the page showing full or php errors such as **(unidentified variable, etc)** and the web page is not working at all. However exact same php files works on remote server **(Godaddy for example)**

the `index.php` file starts with

```
<?
require_once ('templates/header.php');
?>
<div class='grid_12'>
<table>

<div id="form" > and son on....
```

the `header.php` files starts with:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('classes/secure.class.php'); // include the class
$secure = new secure(); // load the class
$secure->secureGlobals(); // run the main class function

require_once ('config.php');
require_once ('functions.php');
require_once ('templates/commonheader.php');
require_once ('lang.php');

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=$charset');

?> and so on...
```

I assume there is a problem with `PHP SESSIONS` in **localhost**. I dont know why the same script is not working in **localhost**. Any help is appreciated.

J.

Comment: I think your server is development environment and show all the warnings or error, and your localhost does not show

Answer (score 5):

Please try this:

1. If you use wamp server go php.ini file
2. Open file and search session.auto_start.
3. Replace session.auto_start = 0 to  session.auto_start = 1.
4. Restart your server.

Answer (score 0):

*When I open index.php on localhost - the page showing full or php errors such as (unidentified variable, etc)*

your localhost is configured to display all errors or in development mode and your server is in production mode that usually display fatal errors only

*and the web page is not working at all. However exact same php files works on remote server (Godaddy for example)*

there are many reason it was working on your server but not in your localhost 
some of them are..
1. PHP extension that is enabled in your server but not in your localhost.
2. Different PHP version?
3. php.ini settings

try to run phpinfo(); function both in your server and in your localhost.